# QTreeView: how to be inform of the beginning/end of item expansion?

Tags: qt, signals, qtreeview

I have a QtreeView that is displaying file lists (using a model derived from QFileSystemModel). As the building of the file list needs a lot of time (I must read the content of each file to determine if the file is visible or not) I want to display the wait cursor during the analysis process. The wait cursor must starts when the user select an item (directory), and stays as long as all the list is not displayed.

For this I did a lot of tries:

- using the expanded signal. But this signal is not related to drawing. Hence it arrves almost immediately,
- managing the cursor in data() function of my model. But in this case I have an horrible blinking cursor,
- managing the cursor by overridding the painEvent. In this case I have a small blinking, and the cursor appears lately
- ...

So, none of my "solutions" is perfect. Hence, do you have a way to do what I want?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One more idea, but i did't try it:

Try to check [QAbstractItemView::State](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#State-enum) in a timer after *QTreeView::expanded()* signal.